# Generate bibtex citation automatically from Google Scholar

Tags: bibtex, google-scholar

I used Google Scholar to search for papers. And then click the 'cite' shown as a quote("). Then choose 'BibTeX' to export it.

Strangely, the bibtex shown will not contain the field of 'url', which should not be difficult to find. Because when you search for papers, each result of paper shown itself is a link.

As far as I known, I didn't find a way to make it add 'url' as well in the bibtex generated automatically. So I have to copy the link and add manually to the bibtex file. Is there a way to automate this procedure? Or I maybe need to write a spider to do this?

Thank you for your time! Any comments will be much appreicated!

Comment: Very often Google scholar gives several links to the paper you are looking for, and has no mean to decide which one is appropriate for your task. Do you prefer link to ArXiv or Hal, to journal page, a DOI or direct to PDF, etc ? If you identify the proper link, is is rather straightforward to add it.

Comment: On an other hand you could have a look at [Zotero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zotero) which stores much more complete record for selected papers, including, URL, DOI, ISBN aso. It build collections in the cloud, ans then allows to export as `.bib` file.